# Spring Dependency not working with Webservices

Tags: web-services, spring, jaxb

I have exposed a service in application as Webservice, but it is not getting handal to a Dao which is injected through Dao, any one has any idaa?
Stack

> Sep 23, 2011 6:48:58 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse
>   mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not
>   be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.scor.omega2.reference.services.impl.CurrencyServiceImpl.getCurrency(CurrencyServiceImpl.java:33)
>     at
>   com.scor.omega2.reference.services.impl.CurrencyServiceImpl.getCurrency(CurrencyServiceImpl.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)

Code

```
@Path("/currency")
@Named("currencyService")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class CurrencyServiceImpl implements CurrencyService {

    @Inject
    private CurrencyDao currencyDao;

    /**
     * Service to get Currency Code Value
     * 
     * @param cur_cf
     * @param lag_cf
     * @return entity.
     */
    public BrefTcurl getCurrency(String cur_cf, char lag_cf) {
        return currencyDao.getCurrency(cur_cf, lag_cf);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Path("{cur_cf}/{lag_cf}")
    public BrefTcurl getCurrency(@PathParam("cur_cf") String cur_cf, @PathParam("lag_cf") String lag_cf) {
        System.out.println("cur_cf "+cur_cf +" lag_cf "+lag_cf);
        return getCurrency(cur_cf,lag_cf.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Currency Dao Class

```
@Named("currencyDao")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class CurrencyDaoImpl implements CurrencyDao
{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * Service to get Currency Code Value
 * 
 * @param cur_cf
 * @param lag_cf
 * @return entity.
 */
public BrefTcurl getCurrency(String cur_cf, char lag_cf)
{
    return entityManager.find(BrefTcurl.class, new BrefTcurlId(lag_cf, cur_cf));
}

}
```

Comment: Is this configured through xml or annotations?  If xml, can we see the xml configuration?  If annotations can we see both xml configuration and the `CurrencyDao` class?

Comment: This is through the anotation. Will add the class code as soon I reach office tomorrow morning..

Comment: Added the Dao code. Please suggest if you find any issue. The code work perfect with normal Web application flow(Without Web services.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the servlet you have configured in web.xml is the wrong one. You need to use the one that is aware of spring and delegates to spring managed beans for processing the request.

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
```

Comment: We are using annotation based dependancies.